# Can't import module from library

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I have a script that requires two other modules to be loaded from another folder in the same directory as the script.

In the main script I have the line:

```
from modules import *
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ts3'
```

I have an `__init__.py` file in the `modules` folder which has this line:

```
__all__ = ['setjoin', 'ts3']
```

Python is for some reason unable to load just the `ts3` module. **It is able to load `setjoin` completely fine.**

Folder structure:

```
MAOW\
    maow.py
    \modules\
        __init__.py
        setjoin.py
        ts3.py
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. I'm not sure why I did this, but I was trying to `import maow` from ts3.py. I've now removed that import and it works fine :)